# Other: IO error: lock hold by current process, acquire time 1685847508 acquiring thread 196910: /tmp/chains/dev/frontier/db/LOCK: No locks available

Tags: relay-chain, evm

I'm adding EVM compatibility to relay chain whie doing so I faced  this error after running my blockchain. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't close your previous node or you close it unproperly.

Try to find out and close that node. If no node is running. Simply delete that FILE.

```
/tmp/chains/dev/frontier/db/LOCK
```

---

BTW, I guess you are developing. Maybe you don't care about the cache. Simply remove the entire DB also works for you.

And if you use `--tmp` in the command, it will use a new path every time. So, you don't need to care about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions present in the `relay-chain(fn partial)` and `(fn new_full)` in which variables are defined multiple times . Go through them and give single definition for `each variable`. I hope this will solve your error.